# Unable to fetch DOM element reference in AfterviewInit in angular 2, also with timeout able to set focus in Chrome not IE

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Forced to use `setTimeout()`, working fine in chrome but not in IE

```js
ngAfterViewInit(){
     setTimeout(()=>{
            this.businessInfoName._inputElement.nativeElement.focus();
     },2000);
}
```

```html
<md-input
    class="firstField" 
    autofocus 
    [ngClass]="{submitted:searchClicked}"
    #businessInfoName 
    [(ngModel)]="submission.accountHolderCompany.contactName"
    aria-placeholder="Name of Business"
    placeholder="Name of Business"
    required
    name="businessname"
    (focus)="v_businessName = true"
    (blur)="v_businessName = false;replaceSpacesWithEmpty()" 
    #businessName="ngModel"
    restrictKey
    maxlength="50"
></md-input>
```

Comment: Try to run IE outside DevMode. IE console steals your focus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of referencing the element on the scope of the component use a `ViewChild` decorator to grab a reference to the element in class and then reference it in the `ngAfterViewInit` like so:

```js
@ViewChild('businessInfoName') businessInfoNameRef: TemplateRef;

ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.businessInfoNameRef.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

## [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/q9htSPjdwhH8N44Pfbap?p=preview)

Comment: It is `ElementRef`, not `TemplateRef`. To get `TemplateRef`, you should add `{ read: TemplateRef }` as a second parameter to `ViewChild` decorator.

Comment: But, in this case, you need `ElementRef`.